# SimpleGeofence cannot be resovled

Tags: java, android, geofencing

I am trying out a code I picked up online, it is something to do with `geofencing`, I want to see how it works and how I can apply the same principle, in my Project, it seems a lot of change took place in the era of `geofencing`, classes seem not to be working as expected and there is no solid documentation and examples, so here is a line of the code

```
public static void addMarkerForFence(SimpleGeofence fence)
```

The keyword "SimpleGeofence" cannot be resolved, I honestly do not know how to approach this error, I do not know how to use the new classes, can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using this class https://developer.android.com/samples/Geofencing/Application/src/com.example.android.wearable.geofencing/SimpleGeofence.html

You need to add it to your project it's not part of the android library.

Comment: :D Gracious God, and I just did this without reading your comment, I went through the project and found it was actually a class, i imported it and all is working, Thanks Very Much though.